# Are "Paper and colors made from pigments mixed with water" considered instruments, tools, or equipment?

Tags: word-choice

Instrument or tool or equipment
I cannot get my head around those words and cannot use them properly.
Let me give you a sentence.

Paper and colors made from pigments mixed with water only are essential
_____ for water colour painting.

What should I use in this blank?
Please help me
I will appreciate all answers.

Comment: *Prerequisites*, perhaps.

Comment: *materials*, maybe

Comment: _Instruments_ and _tools_ are physical objects for carrying out a task (such as brushes, in this case), so if you must choose one of those three words, _equipment_ is the best.

Comment: Note that instruments and tools do not need to be used up.

Comment: Ambiguous: Paper and colors made from pigments mixed with water Not ambiguous: Colors made from pigments mixed with water and paper etc.

Answer (score 0):

Paper and colors made from pigments mixed with water only are essential *elements* *in* water colour painting.

Note:  I changed the preposition "for" to "in".  You could also use "of".  But "for" doesn't sound idiomatic to my ear.